# The name service does not exist in current context and WebReferrence error

Tags: c#, asp.net

Hi i am trying to use this code to pull from a webservice and I am reciving these errors and i do not know why.  I have tried everything...

Errors:

```
The name 'service' does not exist in the current context
```

and

```
WebReference.CheckPartStatus.Parts' cannot be used like a method.
```

My code:

```
    string CustomerID = "5943197";
    // 1off


    WebReference.WebServiceTyped ws = new WebReference.WebServiceTyped();
    WebReference.CheckPartStatus PQ = new WebReference.CheckPartStatus();
    string Parts = "";
    string PartNumber = Parts;
    string PriceSum = null;
    long QtySum = 0;

    PartNumber = "RS5117";
    if (PartNumber == "RS5117")
    {
        PQ = ws.CheckPartNumberStatus(PartNumber, CustomerID, "1,6,8,9,112", "", "", "");
        PriceSum = String.Format(PQ.Parts(0).Cost, "####.00");

        Label1.Text = PriceSum;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Well somewhere there is a variable called `service` which is not declared in the scope, you should be able to Ctrl+F and find it no problem, it's not actually in the code above.

The other error is complaining about this line I believe:

```
PriceSum = String.Format(PQ.Parts(0).Cost, "####.00");
```

Where you call on PQ.Parts(0) as a method. It should probably be:

```
PriceSum = String.Format(PQ.Parts[0].Cost, "####.00");
```

at a guess, or otherwise `PQ.Parts.Cost` if it's not indexed at all, because Parts is a property, not a method.